# Object controller and code not being executed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, controller

I created a very simple new Cocoa application, with a new class and custom controller (or object in interface builder, the plain blue cube). I connected all outlets with interface builder and assigned the custom delegate to the class. The problem is, the code does not get executed (checked by setting breakpoints), the window presents itself, and there are no errors.

The code of the class is really irrelevant, I tried once before with a proper set up and it worked there, I couldn't spot the difference however.

The key here is a separate controller together with class instead of the standard App's Delegate, to integrate the project to a bigger one.

[image: interface builder setup]

Comment: Have you set the correct type of the IB object in the 'Identity Inspector' Tab?

Comment: Thanks @bsarr007 I set it to the class "LogNavigator", it autocompleted, and the arrow on the right hand in the text field showed up (the class inspection arrow).